# Transferring data from a UITableViewCell cocoa touch class to a UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Okay, so what I am essentially trying to do is transfer data from a UITableViewCell class to a UIViewController class. Below is my UITableViewCell:

```
class OrderCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

var post: OrderModel!
var link: Link!

var addedList: [String:Float] = [:]


@IBOutlet weak var dishName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dishDescriptionAndPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfOrders: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addOrderBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var subtractOderBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if numberOfOrders.text == "9" {
        numberOfOrders.text = "9"
    } else {
        numberOfOrders.text = String((Int(numberOfOrders.text!)! + 1))
    }
    addedList.updateValue(post.dishPrice, forKey: post.dishName)
    print(addedList)
}

@IBAction func subtractButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if numberOfOrders.text == "0" {
        numberOfOrders.text = "0"
    } else {
        numberOfOrders.text = String((Int(numberOfOrders.text!)! - 1))
    }
}

func getOrders() -> Dictionary<String, Float> {
    return addedList
}


func configureCell(post: OrderModel) {
    self.post = post
    self.dishName.text = post.dishName
    self.dishDescriptionAndPrice.text = post.dishDescription
    self.numberOfOrders.text = "0"
}

}
```

What I am trying to do, is have my other class (which is of UIViewController), retrieve 'addedList' from the above class. I obviously cannot use prepareForSegue, and I have had no luck find a way to do this that is compatible with these two classes. I am open to creating a new class to be the "bridge" between the two and transfer the data through, but I again cannot find a way to do this. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

To get more specific, the UIViewController holds my tableview, and the class that is above is just the object file for each individual cell. I need to transfer the data when the addButtonPressed IBaction is called.

Comment: Is your UIViewController the class containing your table view? What is the link between the 2? When do you want to retrieve the 'addedList' from the cell? When a cell is selected?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question on the bottom to answer these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a delegate in your cell class. And in your view controller class, under cell for row at indexPath, add:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

And update your cell class like this:

```
 protocol ClassNameDelegate:class {
      func addButtonAction(addedList:[String:Float])
    }

        @IBOutlet weak var dishName: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var dishDescriptionAndPrice: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var numberOfOrders: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var addOrderBtn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var subtractOderBtn: UIButton!


        //Create a delegate

       weak var delegate: ClassNameDelegate?

        @IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
            if numberOfOrders.text == "9" {
                numberOfOrders.text = "9"
            } else {
                numberOfOrders.text = String((Int(numberOfOrders.text!)! + 1))
            }
            addedList.updateValue(post.dishPrice, forKey: post.dishName)
            print(addedList)

            // Call this when added list is done and get the call to your view controller.

            if delegate != nil {
               delegate?.addButtonAction(addedList: addedList)
            }
        }

        @IBAction func subtractButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
            if numberOfOrders.text == "0" {
                numberOfOrders.text = "0"
            } else {
                numberOfOrders.text = String((Int(numberOfOrders.text!)! - 1))
            }
        }

        func getOrders() -> Dictionary<String, Float> {
            return addedList
        }


        func configureCell(post: OrderModel) {
            self.post = post
            self.dishName.text = post.dishName
            self.dishDescriptionAndPrice.text = post.dishDescription
            self.numberOfOrders.text = "0"
        }

        }
```

Finally import this delegate method in your view controller class, in the same way you import tableView delegate and datasource.

Comment: This is giving me an error that my UIViewControllerClass does not conform to protocol 'ClassNameDelegate'

Comment: Did you import this method: func addButtonAction(addedList:[String:Float]) in your view controller class?

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with protocols and conformance to them, it's kind of fundamental to the language you're writing in...

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly what I wanted  to do. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

A cell is not the good place to store information like this. You should store the information in your view controller. And when your cell button is pressed, retrieve the information thanks to the index path of the cell.

In your cell:

```
func configureCell(post: OrderModel, delegate:UIViewController) {
    self.dishName.text = post.dishName
    self.dishDescriptionAndPrice.text = post.dishDescription
    self.numberOfOrders.text = "0"
    self.addButton.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(delegate.addButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
}
```

In your view controller:

```
//store your data in your view controller
var data=[OrderModel]()

func addButtonPressed(_ button:UIButton){
    let selectedCell=button.superview?.superview? as! OrderCell
    let indexPath=tableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell)
    let cellData=data[indexPath!.row]

    if cellData.numberOfOrders==9{
        selectedCell.numberOfOrders.text="9"
    }else{
        selectedCell.numberOfOrders.text=String(cellData.numberOfOrders+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems to be giving me an error that 'UIControlEvents' has no member 'touchUpInside'

Comment: Strange, are you coding in Swift 3?

Comment: What does it propose you when you start typing?